# Cover images of posts are not displaying in my blogger blog

Tags: blogger, html, css

I am using a custom theme template for my blog. I had setup & configured it according to my own style. but now in my every post, cover images are not displaying for those particular customize gadgets. How can I resolve this issue?

For example:

This is the screenshot of custom gadget of "hot widgets" which displays some posts in my blog randomly.
[image]

But in my blog posts cover images are not displayed as you can see in below screenshot

[image]

I have tried some CSS code to auto fit the images but not working for me. please suggest..